# « L'araignée est sur le plafond »

Tags: prépositions, indications-de-lieu

Je suis dans ma chambre. Je lève le regard et, hélas, je vois une araignée.

Si l'araignée est en contact avec le plafond, est ce-que je peux dire « l'araignée est *sur* le plafond » ? Peut-être devrais-je dire « l'araignée est *dans* le plafond » ou « l'araignée est *au* plafond » ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oui, « l'araignée est sur le plafond » se dit couramment. Ici « sur » veut dire « à la surface de », indépendamment du haut et du bas, comme on dit « sur le mur ». On peut aussi dire « l'araignée est au plafond » mais c'est peut-être plus rare à cause de l'expression « avoir une araignée au plafond » qui signifie être un peu timbré.

« L'araignée est dans le plafond » pourrait éventuellement se dire d'une araignée qui s'est cachée dans un faux-plafond. On ne le dira pas si elle est visible.

Answer (score 1):

Fréquence de *[sur](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sur%20le%20plafond%2Cau%20plafond%2Csous%20le%20plafond%2Cdans%20le%20plafond&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csur%20le%20plafond%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cau%20plafond%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csous%20le%20plafond%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdans%20le%20plafond%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csur%20le%20plafond%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cau%20plafond%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csous%20le%20plafond%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdans%20le%20plafond%3B%2Cc0)* le plafond, *au* plafond, *sous* le plafond, *dans* le plafond

Il y a un sens matériel avec *au* (à la surface) et *dans* (à l’intérieur) et conceptuel (dans les statistiques par exemple) autrement.

Familièrement  « il a une araignée au plafond » ou « il a une araignée dans le plafond » signifie qu’il n’a pas les idées très claires, qu’il n’est pas fou à lier, mais qu’il lui marque quelque chose pour comprendre le monde : « il est *[cinglé](https://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/cingl%C3%A9)* ! » son monde cérébral est dé-rangé, perturbé, incohérent.